# How to find records in sequelize-mySql where parent table doesnt have child records

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a **Parent table** which have following columns

**Parent_a, Parent_b**

I have **child table** which  **have or haven't** records for parent table

I have to find all records which desn't have  records in column **Parent_a,Parent_b**  or in **child table**

**for example**
user Table
**id - name  -address**
   1  -  abc   -1/a NYC
   2   - xyz   -2/a NYC
   3   - mnc   -3/a NYC

child Table
**id - user id  language**
   1  -  1   -French
   1   - 2   -English

**another table which is not associated**
**id - user id - plan name**
   1  -  1   -plan 1
   1   - 3   -plan 2
**here result should be like below :**
 2   - xyz   -2/a NYC
 3   - mnc   -3/a NYC
How can i achieve that **through sequelize join** and i am not using raw query as well

Comment: Please add more description of the issue you want to solve. Probably models of Parent table and child table and some code of sequelize statements will help to understand your problem better.

Comment: i want to find all data which doesnt have record in child table

Comment: Raw queries are there for a reason and this may be one of those cases, this is a little bit above the paygrade of the built in query functionality in my opinion... Is there a reason you don't want to use a raw query - i suppose you maybe could do a very detailed where clause but at that point you would likely have much better code using the raw query option

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info there to properly answer this question but you could just use a raw Query for that

```
const result = await models.sequelize.query('Query from mySQL that returned your desired results pasted here with dynamic parameter or parameters if desired like :tag_id; ',
      { replacements: { tag_id: args.id }, type: models.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

If you actually showed us your models or table structure i am sure we could help you with the query if you needed it

Comment: i have update the question, please take a moment to review it,and i am not using raw queries

Answer (score 0):

after digging few hours ,I found solution **if any one stuck with issue**

```
let result = await tableA.count({
where: {
    [Op.or]: [{
        field_m: ''
    }, {
        field_n: ''
    }, {
        field_o: ''
    }, {
        field_p: ''
    }, {
        field_q: ''
    }, {
        field_r: ''
    }, {
        field_s: ''
    }, {
        field_t: ''
    }, {
        '$tableB.tableC.id$': null
    }, ],
    id: {
        [Op.ne]: constants.ROLES.SA
    },
    is_deleted: false
},
include: {
    model: tableB,
    through: {
        attributes: ['id'],
        where: {
            is_deleted: false
        },
        required: false
    },
    required: false
},
group: ['id'],
attributes: [
    "id",
    [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("$tableB.tableC.id$")), "count"],
],
```

})